# Nan in summary histogram for: deconv2/biases

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, cudnn, semantic-segmentation

The original size of my images is 3900 x 6000 x 3. I make overlapping patches of shape (232024, 28, 28, 3) and then make batches of size 1000. I have a CNN model for semantic segmentation as follows:

```
def conv_layer(inputs, filters, kernel_size, strides = 1, padding = "SAME", bias_constant = 0.0, name = "conv"):
    with tf.name_scope(name):
        input_shape = inputs.shape.as_list()

        filter_tensor = tf.truncated_normal([kernel_size[0], kernel_size[1], input_shape[3], filters], dtype = tf.float32)

        filter = tf.Variable(initial_value = filter_tensor, trainable = True, name = "kernel")
        bias = tf.Variable(tf.constant(bias_constant, shape=[filters]), name="bias")

        conv2d = tf.nn.conv2d(input = tf.cast(inputs, dtype = tf.float32), filter = filter, strides = [1, strides, strides, 1], padding = padding)

        activation = tf.nn.relu(conv2d + bias)

        tf.summary.histogram("weights", filter)
        tf.summary.histogram("biases", bias)
        tf.summary.histogram("activations", activation)

        return tf.cast(activation, dtype = tf.float16)

def deconv_layer(inputs, filters, kernel_size, output_size, strides = 1, padding = "SAME", bias_constant = 0.0, name = "deconv"):
    with tf.name_scope(name):

        input_shape = inputs.shape.as_list()
        deconv_shape = tf.stack([tf.shape(inputs)[0], output_size[0], output_size[1],filters])

        filter_tensor = tf.truncated_normal([kernel_size[0], kernel_size[1], filters, input_shape[3]], dtype = tf.float32)

        filter = tf.Variable(initial_value = filter_tensor, trainable = True, name = "kernel")
        bias = tf.Variable(tf.constant(bias_constant, shape=[filters]), name="bias")

        print("bias:")
        print(bias)

        conv2d_transpose = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(value = tf.cast(inputs, dtype = tf.float32), 
                                                  filter = filter, 
                                                  strides = [1, strides, strides, 1], 
                                                  output_shape=deconv_shape,
                                                  padding = padding)

        activation = tf.nn.relu(conv2d_transpose + bias)

        tf.summary.histogram("weights", filter)
        tf.summary.histogram("biases", bias)
        tf.summary.histogram("activations", activation)

        return tf.cast(activation, dtype = tf.float16)

def semantic_seg_model(features, mode, batch_size):
    bias_constant = 0.1
    conv_filters = [20, 50, 90]
    conv_sizes = []

    tf.summary.image('input', features, batch_size)

    """Model function for CNN."""

    # Encoding starts here.

    # Convolutional Layer 1
    # Input: 100 x 100
    conv = conv_layer(inputs=features,
                        filters=conv_filters[0],
                        kernel_size=[5, 5],
                        bias_constant = bias_constant,
                        name = "conv1")

    conv_sizes.append(conv.shape.as_list())
    print(conv.shape)

    # Convolutional Layer 2
    # Input: 100 x 100
    conv = conv_layer(inputs = conv,
                        filters = conv_filters[1],
                        kernel_size = [5, 5],
                        strides = 2,
                        bias_constant = bias_constant,
                        name = "conv2")

    conv_sizes.append(conv.shape.as_list())
    print(conv.shape)
    # Convolutional Layer 3
    # Input: 100 x 100
    conv = conv_layer(inputs = conv,
                        filters = conv_filters[2],
                        kernel_size = [5, 5],
                        bias_constant = bias_constant,
                        strides = 2,
                        name = "conv3")

    conv_sizes.append(conv.shape.as_list())
    print(conv.shape)

    # Deconvolution Layer 3
    # Input: 100 x 100
    deconv = deconv_layer(inputs = conv,
                            filters = conv_filters[1],
                            kernel_size = [5, 5],
                            bias_constant = bias_constant,
                            strides = 2,
                            output_size = [conv_sizes[1][1], conv_sizes[1][2]],
                            name = "deconv3")
    print(deconv.shape)
    # Deconvolution Layer 2
    # Input: 100 x 100
    deconv = deconv_layer(inputs = deconv,
                            filters = conv_filters[0],
                            kernel_size = [5, 5],
                            bias_constant = bias_constant,
                            strides = 2,
                            output_size = [conv_sizes[0][1], conv_sizes[0][2]],
                            name = "deconv2")
    print(deconv.shape)
    deconv = deconv_layer(inputs = deconv,
                            filters = 3,
                            kernel_size = [5, 5],
                            output_size = [features.shape.as_list()[1], features.shape.as_list()[2]],
                            bias_constant = bias_constant,
                            name = "deconv1")

    print(deconv.shape)
    return deconv

epochs = 1000
learning_rate = 1e-50

image, label = tf.train.slice_input_producer([features, labels], shuffle = False)

BATCH_SIZE = 1000
THREAD_NUM = 5
MIN_AFTER_DEQUEUE = 10000
queue_capacity = MIN_AFTER_DEQUEUE + THREAD_NUM * BATCH_SIZE


image_batch, label_batch = tf.train.batch(tensors = [image, label],
                                            batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
                                            capacity = queue_capacity,
                                            num_threads = THREAD_NUM,
                                            allow_smaller_final_batch = True)

output = semantic_seg_model(image_batch, tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN, BATCH_SIZE)

#cost
with tf.name_scope("cross_entropy"):
    cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = output, labels = label_batch)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean( cross_entropy )
#     return cost, optimizer, accr
    tf.summary.scalar("xent", cost)

#optimizer
with tf.name_scope("optimizer"):
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# Accuracy
with tf.name_scope("accuracy"):
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(label_batch, 1), tf.argmax(output, 1))
    accr = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float16))
    tf.summary.scalar("accuracy", accr)

merged_summary = tf.summary.merge_all()

# Session configs
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.log_device_placement = True
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
# config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.8

# Initialize session
sess = tf.Session(config=config)

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
enqueue_threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess = sess, coord = coord)

try:
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        if coord.should_stop():
            break

        epoch_loss = 0
        train_loss = []; train_accuracy = []

        s = sess.run(merged_summary)
        writer.add_summary(s, epoch)

        for batch in range(math.ceil(features.shape.as_list()[0]/BATCH_SIZE)):
            _, sess_cost, sess_accuracy = sess.run([optimizer, cost, accr])

            train_loss.append(sess_cost)
            train_accuracy.append(sess_accuracy)

        train_loss = np.mean(train_loss)
        train_accuracy = np.mean(train_accuracy)

        saver.save(sess, "./semantic_seg_model_1", global_step=epoch)

        print ("[%02d/%02d] trainLoss: %.4f trainAcc: %.2f" 
           % (epoch + 1, epochs, sess_cost, sess_accuracy))

except Exception as e:
        # Report exceptions to the coordinator.
    coord.request_stop(e)

finally:
        # Terminate as usual. It is safe to call `coord.request_stop()` twice.
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(enqueue_threads)

sess.close()
```

I get an error when I start the training session. The error is as follows:

> [01/1000] trainLoss: 0.0000 trainAcc: 1.00
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: , Nan
>   in summary histogram for: deconv2/biases   [[Node: deconv2/biases =
>   HistogramSummary[T=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](deconv2/biases/tag,
>   deconv2/bias/read/_105)]]      [[Node: batch/fifo_queue_Size/_91 =
>   _Recvclient_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0",
>   send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0",
>   send_device_incarnation=1,
>   tensor_name="edge_37_batch/fifo_queue_Size", tensor_type=DT_INT32,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]]
>
> Caused by op 'deconv2/biases', defined at:   File "c:\users\fawad
>   khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193,
>   in _run_module_as_main
>       "**main**", mod_spec)   File "c:\users\fawad khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85,
>   in _run_code
>       exec(code, run_globals)   File "c:\users\fawad khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py",
>   line 16, in 
>       app.launch_new_instance()   File "c:\users\fawad khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py",
>   line 658, in launch_instance
>       app.start()   File "c:\users\fawad khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py",
>   line 478, in start
>       self.io_loop.start()   File "c:\users\fawad khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\ioloop.py",
>   line 177, in start
>       super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()   File "c:\users\fawad khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py",
>   line 888, in start
>       handler_func(fd_obj, events)   File "c:\users\fawad khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py",
>   line 277, in null_wrapper
>       return fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "c:\users\fawad khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py",
>   line 440, in _handle_events
>       self._handle_recv()   File "c:\users\fawad khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py",
>   line 472, in _handle_recv
>       self._run_callback(callback, msg)   File "c:\users\fawad khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py",
>   line 414, in _run_callback
>       callback(*args, **kwargs)   File "c:\users\fawad khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py",
>   line 277, in null_wrapper
>       return fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "c:\users\fawad khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py",
>   line 281, in dispatcher
>       return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)   File "c:\users\fawad khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py",
>   line 232, in dispatch_shell
>       handler(stream, idents, msg)   File "c:\users\fawad khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py",
>   line 397, in execute_request
>       user_expressions, allow_stdin)   File "c:\users\fawad khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py",
>   line 208, in do_execute
>       res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)   File "c:\users\fawad
>   khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py",
>   line 533, in run_cell
>       return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)   File "c:\users\fawad
>   khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py",
>   line 2728, in run_cell
>       interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)   File "c:\users\fawad
>   khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py",
>   line 2850, in run_ast_nodes
>       if self.run_code(code, result):   File "c:\users\fawad khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py",
>   line 2910, in run_code
>       exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)   File "", line 1, in 
>       output = semantic_seg_model(image_batch, tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN, BATCH_SIZE)   File
>   "", line 107, in semantic_seg_model
>       name = "deconv2")   File "", line 78, in deconv_layer
>       tf.summary.histogram("biases", bias)   File "c:\users\fawad khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\summary\summary.py",
>   line 192, in histogram
>       tag=tag, values=values, name=scope)   File "c:\users\fawad khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_logging_ops.py",
>   line 187, in _histogram_summary
>       "HistogramSummary", tag=tag, values=values, name=name)   File "c:\users\fawad
>   khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py",
>   line 787, in _apply_op_helper
>       op_def=op_def)   File "c:\users\fawad khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 2956, in create_op
>       op_def=op_def)   File "c:\users\fawad khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 1470, in **init**
>       self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
>
> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Nan in summary
>   histogram for: deconv2/biases      [[Node: deconv2/biases =
>   HistogramSummary[T=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](deconv2/biases/tag,
>   deconv2/bias/read/_105)]]      [[Node: batch/fifo_queue_Size/_91 =
>   _Recvclient_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0",
>   send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0",
>   send_device_incarnation=1,
>   tensor_name="edge_37_batch/fifo_queue_Size", tensor_type=DT_INT32,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]]
>
> Number of iterations completed this epoch: 0
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------- InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call
>   last) c:\users\fawad
>   khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py
>   in _do_call(self, fn, *args)    1322     try:
>   -> 1323       return fn(*args)    1324     except errors.OpError as e:
>
> c:\users\fawad
>   khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py
>   in _run_fn(session, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options,
>   run_metadata)    1301                                    feed_dict,
>   fetch_list, target_list,
>   -> 1302                                    status, run_metadata)    1303
>
> c:\users\fawad
>   khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py
>   in **exit**(self, type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)
>       472             compat.as_text(c_api.TF_Message(self.status.status)),
>   --> 473             c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
>       474     # Delete the underlying status object from memory otherwise it stays alive
>
> InvalidArgumentError: Nan in summary histogram for: deconv2/biases
>   [[Node: deconv2/biases = HistogramSummary[T=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](deconv2/biases/tag,
>   deconv2/bias/read/_105)]]      [[Node: batch/fifo_queue_Size/_91 =
>   _Recvclient_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0",
>   send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0",
>   send_device_incarnation=1,
>   tensor_name="edge_37_batch/fifo_queue_Size", tensor_type=DT_INT32,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]]
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        40         # Terminate as usual. It is safe to call `coord.request_stop()` twice.
>        41     coord.request_stop()
>   ---> 42     coord.join(enqueue_threads)
>        43 
>        44 sess.close()
>
> c:\users\fawad
>   khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\coordinator.py
>   in join(self, threads, stop_grace_period_secs, ignore_live_threads)
>       387       self._registered_threads = set()
>       388       if self._exc_info_to_raise:
>   --> 389         six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise)
>       390       elif stragglers:
>       391         if ignore_live_threads:
>
> c:\users\fawad
>   khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\six.py
>   in reraise(tp, value, tb)
>       691             if value.**traceback** is not tb:
>       692                 raise value.with_traceback(tb)
>   --> 693             raise value
>       694         finally:
>       695             value = None
>
> in ()
>        13         train_loss = []; train_accuracy = []
>        14 
>   ---> 15         s = sess.run(merged_summary)
>        16         writer.add_summary(s, epoch)
>        17
>
> c:\users\fawad
>   khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py
>   in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
>       887     try:
>       888       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
>   --> 889                          run_metadata_ptr)
>       890       if run_metadata:
>       891         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)
>
> c:\users\fawad
>   khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py
>   in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
>   1118     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and
>   feed_dict_tensor):    1119       results = self._do_run(handle,
>   final_targets, final_fetches,
>   -> 1120                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)    1121     else:    1122       results = []
>
> c:\users\fawad
>   khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py
>   in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options,
>   run_metadata)    1315     if handle is None:    1316       return
>   self._do_call(_run_fn, self._session, feeds, fetches, targets,
>   -> 1317                            options, run_metadata)    1318     else:    1319       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, self._session,
>   handle, feeds, fetches)
>
> c:\users\fawad
>   khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py
>   in _do_call(self, fn, *args)    1334         except KeyError:    1335 
>   pass
>   -> 1336       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)    1337     1338   def _extend_graph(self):
>
> InvalidArgumentError: Nan in summary histogram for: deconv2/biases
>   [[Node: deconv2/biases = HistogramSummary[T=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](deconv2/biases/tag,
>   deconv2/bias/read/_105)]]      [[Node: batch/fifo_queue_Size/_91 =
>   _Recvclient_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0",
>   send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0",
>   send_device_incarnation=1,
>   tensor_name="edge_37_batch/fifo_queue_Size", tensor_type=DT_INT32,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]]
>
> Caused by op 'deconv2/biases', defined at:   File "c:\users\fawad
>   khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193,
>   in _run_module_as_main
>       "**main**", mod_spec)   File "c:\users\fawad khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85,
>   in _run_code
>       exec(code, run_globals)   File "c:\users\fawad khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py",
>   line 16, in 
>       app.launch_new_instance()   File "c:\users\fawad khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py",
>   line 658, in launch_instance
>       app.start()   File "c:\users\fawad khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py",
>   line 478, in start
>       self.io_loop.start()   File "c:\users\fawad khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\ioloop.py",
>   line 177, in start
>       super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()   File "c:\users\fawad khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py",
>   line 888, in start
>       handler_func(fd_obj, events)   File "c:\users\fawad khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py",
>   line 277, in null_wrapper
>       return fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "c:\users\fawad khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py",
>   line 440, in _handle_events
>       self._handle_recv()   File "c:\users\fawad khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py",
>   line 472, in _handle_recv
>       self._run_callback(callback, msg)   File "c:\users\fawad khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py",
>   line 414, in _run_callback
>       callback(*args, **kwargs)   File "c:\users\fawad khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py",
>   line 277, in null_wrapper
>       return fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "c:\users\fawad khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py",
>   line 281, in dispatcher
>       return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)   File "c:\users\fawad khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py",
>   line 232, in dispatch_shell
>       handler(stream, idents, msg)   File "c:\users\fawad khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py",
>   line 397, in execute_request
>       user_expressions, allow_stdin)   File "c:\users\fawad khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py",
>   line 208, in do_execute
>       res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)   File "c:\users\fawad
>   khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py",
>   line 533, in run_cell
>       return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)   File "c:\users\fawad
>   khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py",
>   line 2728, in run_cell
>       interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)   File "c:\users\fawad
>   khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py",
>   line 2850, in run_ast_nodes
>       if self.run_code(code, result):   File "c:\users\fawad khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py",
>   line 2910, in run_code
>       exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)   File "", line 1, in 
>       output = semantic_seg_model(image_batch, tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN, BATCH_SIZE)   File
>   "", line 107, in semantic_seg_model
>       name = "deconv2")   File "", line 78, in deconv_layer
>       tf.summary.histogram("biases", bias)   File "c:\users\fawad khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\summary\summary.py",
>   line 192, in histogram
>       tag=tag, values=values, name=scope)   File "c:\users\fawad khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_logging_ops.py",
>   line 187, in _histogram_summary
>       "HistogramSummary", tag=tag, values=values, name=name)   File "c:\users\fawad
>   khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py",
>   line 787, in _apply_op_helper
>       op_def=op_def)   File "c:\users\fawad khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 2956, in create_op
>       op_def=op_def)   File "c:\users\fawad khalil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 1470, in **init**
>       self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
>
> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Nan in summary
>   histogram for: deconv2/biases      [[Node: deconv2/biases =
>   HistogramSummary[T=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](deconv2/biases/tag,
>   deconv2/bias/read/_105)]]      [[Node: batch/fifo_queue_Size/_91 =
>   _Recvclient_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0",
>   send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0",
>   send_device_incarnation=1,
>   tensor_name="edge_37_batch/fifo_queue_Size", tensor_type=DT_INT32,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]]

Someone at github tensorflow issues suggested trying reduce the learning rate as the model diverged, but that didn't help. Another one suggested that dtype should be changed to float32 from float16 as float16 is problematic. When I change the dtype of data to float32 then I get the following error in the python log console:

> [libprotobuf ERROR
>   C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\cmake_build\protobuf\src\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\message_lite.cc:297]
>   **Exceeded maximum protobuf size of 2GB**. [libprotobuf ERROR
>   C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\cmake_build\protobuf\src\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\message_lite.cc:297]
>   **Exceeded maximum protobuf size of 2GB**.

This very same error occurs when I try to increase the width and hieght of the overlapping patches of image. I have also tried reducing BATCH_SIZE but didn't help.

I have 4GB NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M dedicated graphics card and 16GB RAM with Intel Core i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60 GHz 2.60 GHz. Python version is 3.6.4 and Tensorflow version is 1.4 with GPU.

**Update 1:**
 Updated model:

```
def semantic_seg_model(features, mode, batch_size):
    bias_constant = 0.1
    conv_filters = [10, 25, 90]
    conv_sizes = []

    tf.summary.image('input', features, batch_size)

    """Model function for CNN."""

    # Encoding starts here.

    # Convolutional Layer 1
    # Input: 100 x 100
    conv = conv_layer(inputs=features,
                        filters=conv_filters[0],
                        kernel_size=[2, 2],
                        bias_constant = bias_constant,
                        name = "conv1")

    conv_sizes.append(conv.shape.as_list())
    print(conv.shape)

    # Convolutional Layer 2
    # Input: 100 x 100
    conv = conv_layer(inputs = conv,
                        filters = conv_filters[1],
                        kernel_size = [2, 2],
                        bias_constant = bias_constant,
                        name = "conv2")

    conv_sizes.append(conv.shape.as_list())
    print(conv.shape)

# Deconvolution Layer 2
    # Input: 100 x 100
    deconv = deconv_layer(inputs = conv,
                            filters = conv_filters[0],
                            kernel_size = [2, 2],
                            bias_constant = bias_constant,
                            output_size = [conv_sizes[0][1], conv_sizes[0][2]],
                            name = "deconv2")
    print(deconv.shape)
    deconv = deconv_layer(inputs = deconv,
                            filters = 3,
                            kernel_size = [2, 2],
                            output_size = [features.shape.as_list()[1], features.shape.as_list()[2]],
                            bias_constant = bias_constant,
                            name = "deconv1")

    print(deconv.shape)
    return tf.cast(deconv, dtype = tf.float16)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the problem is that you have significantly **overfit**; the real evidence here is:

```
[01/1000] trainLoss: 0.0000 trainAcc: 1.00
```

This says that after only one epoch you have perfectly fit to the training data; a sure sign of overfitting.  Thus the resulting `NaN` is probably an unsurprising effect of this problem, since you have now almost certainly have learned weights that will return `0` or `inf` on data or batches that it hasn't seen (since it is so badly overfit).

To resolve this issue, I recommend simplifying your model substantially until you get something that doesn't overfit so quickly; for example, fewer and smaller conv and deconv layers.  Then you can start to build back in that complexity.  You will then also find that you will likely want to build in some dropout and/or batch normalization to deal with this overfitting (note: while it is tempting to just start adding this complexity to your existing model, I recommend against it; get something simple working first, then add complexity from there...).

**Final note**: if you simplify the problem as suggested above you will likely have a better [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to share; that should let us get to the bottom of your problem more quickly.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have updated my model and included in the update. I reduced the number of conv and deconv layers, amount of filters and kernel size, also I was able to reduce the learning rate to 1e-4.
Now model works fine but can you please guide why tf.float32 dtype is not working still and getting the same error about exceeding 2 GB limit of protobuf?

Comment: also I wanted to increase the size of image overlapping patches because I reckon it would give me better accuracy. But could not increase due to exceeded limit error. Is there some work around? It was suggested to create model saver with sharded=True argument but that didn't work.